# fail to build Opencv in windows using code:block

Tags: opencv

Following [this link](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Getting_started). I am stuck in the last two steps during setting up my workstation.

As a compiler I use Code:Block MinGW; I have already generated the compiled opencv files, now I need to build the sln file in Windows. I use Code Block to build this OpenCV Project File in the path D:\OpenCV\Build\Opencv, where I put the generated bin file after using Cmake.

During the building, it stopped at 40%, saying;

> Linking CXX executable ....\bin\opencv_perf_core.exe
>   c:/codeblock/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   warning: auto-importing has been activated without
>   --enable-auto-import specified on the command line. This should work unless it involves constant data structures referencing symbols from
>   auto-imported DLLs. Cannot export _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_13ROp3allEv: symbol
>   not found Cannot export _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_17CmpType3allEv: symbol not
>   found collect2: ld returned 1 exit status mingw32-make.exe[2]: ***
>   [bin/opencv_perf_core.exe] Error 1 mingw32-make.exe[1](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Getting_started): ***
>   [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/all] Error 2
>   mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2 Info: resolving vtable for
>   cv::_OutputArray by linking to **imp**_ZTVN2cv12_OutputArrayE
>   (auto-import) Info: resolving vtable for cv::_InputArray by linking to
>   **imp**_ZTVN2cv11_InputArrayE (auto-import) Info: resolving vtable for cv::Exception by linking to **imp**_ZTVN2cv9ExceptionE (auto-import)
>   Creating library file: ....\bin\libopencv_perf_core.dll.a Process
>   terminated with status 2 (14 minutes, 29 seconds) 0 errors, 3 warnings

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's not much you can do, according to http://code.opencv.org/issues/2523.

You will have to use a recent version of MinGW. It builds fine using the latest MinGW shipping with GCC 4.7.2.

This issue seems to have been introduced in OpenCV 2.4.3 as it is said version 2.4.2 builds fine.